# How do you replace a comma in an input box with another character on post to the database?

Tags: php, database, str-replace

I have an input box which will have data separated by commas.  I want to post to the database these to be replaced with an alternate value.  How could this be done? I am still new to PHP so I would appreciate if you could make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving your value from `$_POST['someValue']`, you can do this:

```
$newValue = str_replace(',','any-separater',$_POST['someValue']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, with comma-separated data, you probably want to extract the values from the string. This will create an array of values from the string.

```
$comma_separated_list = 'foo, bar, baz';
$values = array_map('trim', explode(',', $comma_separated_list));

// Now:
// $values = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
foreach ($values as $value) {
  print $value;
}
```

prints:

`foo`

`bar`

`baz`

As for inserting this data into the database, we'd need to see a database schema to get a better idea of how the data is stored.